# django-cms menu disappeared

Tags: django, django-cms

I am using django-cms 2.2 and my menu suddenly disappeared. There's no error message. Page renders normally, with exception of menu. I am using:

```
{% show_menu 0 0 100 100 "menu/show_menu_template.html" %}
```

command, and as i checked it goes inside of `show_menu_template`.
`showmenu_template` is standard and as follows, it was working before, cheers

```
{% load menu_tags %}
{% for child in children %}

<li class="{% if forloop.last %}last {% endif %}{% if child.selected %}current selected{% endif %}{% if child.ancestor %}ancestor{% endif %}{% if child.sibling %}sibling{% endif %}{% if child.descendant %}descendant{% endif %}">
    <a href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>
    {% if child.children %}
    <ul>
    {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template "" "" child %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
</li> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Did you unpublish any content in the admin? Try `{% show_menu 100 100 100 100 ... %}` to see if there are any links at all in the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the tag inside the template and it started working, am not sure why it was not working before and stopped as such but what to do

```
{% show_menu 1 1 100 100 "menu/show_menu_template.html" %}
```